# Get all orders by "shipped" status that wasn't paid for by "wire transfer"

Tags: mysql, magento-1.4

I'm working directly with a Magento DB, trying to get a list of all orders with an order status of `Shipped`, excluding those paid for via wire transfer (`bankpayment`). Here's my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    so.entity_id, 
    so.created_at, 
    MAX(soe.created_at) AS shipped_at 
  FROM sales_order so 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_order_entity soe 
    ON (soe.parent_id=so.entity_id) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_order_entity_varchar soev 
    ON (soev.entity_id = soe.entity_id) 
    AND (soev.value <> 'bankpayment') 
  WHERE (soev.value = 'shipped') 
  GROUP BY so.entity_id) AS shipped 
WHERE (shipped.shipped_at >= '2013-05-01 04:00:00') 
AND (shipped.shipped_at <= '2013-05-02 03:59:59');
```

I'm not really a SQL expert, and you can see where I'm **trying** to select orders not paid for by wire transfer with this line:

`AND (soev.value <> 'bankpayment')`

But it doesn't work as expected, and I suspect that it has to do with the `WHERE` clause:

`WHERE (soev.value = 'shipped')`

I don't know how to properly write this query. Any advice?

**NOTE** - In this case, I'm not able to use Magento models/collections for gathering the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for entities that have `'shipped`' but not `'bankpayment'`.  You want to look for these values on *different* rows.  In other words, you want to accept an entity that has a row with `'shipped`' but only when there are no rows with `'bankpayment'`.

You can do this logic in the `having` clause.  Well, you don't quite have a `having` clause.  You have a subquery with a `where` clause on the outside.  Although this is equivalent, I'm simplifying the query to eliminate the subquery.  Then, I'm using the `having` clause to check the dates and the presence/absence of the two values:

```
SELECT so.entity_id, so.created_at, 
       MAX(soe.created_at) AS shipped_at 
FROM sales_order so LEFT OUTER JOIN
     sales_order_entity soe 
     ON soe.parent_id = so.entity_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     sales_order_entity_varchar soev 
     ON soev.entity_id = soe.entity_id
GROUP BY so.entity_id
having MAX(soe.created_at) >= '2013-05-01 04:00:00' AND 
       MAX(soe.created_at) <= '2013-05-02 03:59:59' and
       SUM(soev.value = 'shipped') > 0 and
       sum(soev.value = 'bankpayment') = 0;
```

Comment: This worked as expected. I also like that you taught me something about how and when to use a `having` clause. Thanks!